# Windows form application layout checListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently trying to develop a windows form application about school, teacher and students. In this application, I have the ability to choose application by filter a list of student and teacher who is using this application. For the layout, I think for selecting a list of application, I am going to use a combo box to do the trick.

But I cannot think of filtering by teacher and student. Let say when an application is selected, a list of teacher pop up and the user has the ability to chose from this list of teacher and they also have the ability to use select all teachers who popped up. I am thinking of using a checkListBox, but I tried it in some of my own tutorial and I found out you don't even need to click the check box to select that item, you can just click the side of that item and it will do the same (let say trying to get a string for the message box to pop up, the message box will pop up even I checked the items by not checking the check box which is just like list box). I am not sure is this is because of my code or is there some bugs in the check list box?

What I did is I iterate through the checkListbox and check which on is checked. Am I doing this wrong or the foreach loop already did it by .CheckedItems method

```
   foreach(var item in checkListBox.CheckedItems)
     {
          if(something is check){
              // do this      
           }   
      }
```

Comment: With regards to the `CheckedListBox`, what event are you handling?  It sounds like it's `SelectedIndexChanged`, which is wrong.  You're not interested in selection so don't handle an event related to selection.  `ItemCheck` is the event you want.

Comment: Don't ask more than one question at a time.  If have multiple questions, post them each separately.

Comment: I see what you mean thanks a lot. I will separate my question next time thanks.

Comment: Hi jmcihinney, just a question if you have any suggestion on my checkbox?